# Project a circlular "shade" onto objects in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm very new to using GL, so please, bear with me!

I have a plane with a cube resting on top of it. I have 3 SeekBars in the Activity which allow the user to rotate along the x and z axis (aka tilt and rotate), and one to "zoom-in" (aka translate on z-axis). What I'd like to do is allow the user to go into a "bird's-eye view" of the plane and drag their finger along to place a "marker" which will just be a semi-transparent circle.

When the player releases their finger, I'd like the marker to stay where the user has left it. Now, I'd like to be able to rotate the 3D scene and see that the marker is not just a flat circle, but almost like a spotlight - it interacts with other objects (ie the cube).

How would this be done? Do I need to look into something like lighting?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [projective texturing](http://developer.amd.com/gpu_assets/GDC06-GLES_Tutorial_Day-Ginsburg-Advanced_Rendering.pdf).

Comment: Be careful though; on the SGX it'll depend on your GL driver but the PowerVR MBX that's still in a lot of handsets still corners on projective texturing — the interpolation isn't quite right, in a way analogous to the way the original Playstation handled perspective on regular polygons. Use smaller polygons if the output looks wrong.